# Android : How to track Keyboard usage

Tags: java, android, keyboard

Is there a way to track how "fast" a user is on the soft keyboard? I want to konw the time the user takes when using the keyboard.

I hope my question is clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a text watcher in the EditText and on every text change you can calculate the difference in time.

```
long intialTime=System.getCurrentTimeMillis();
long total = 0;

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {  
  
            @Override  
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {  
                total= total + (System.getCurrentTimeMillis()-initialTime)
                intialTime = System.getCurrentTimeMillis();
            }  
  
            @Override  
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) 
            {  
               
            }  
  
            @Override  
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {  
                
            }  
        });
```